# Regex i18next parse handlebars

Tags: regex, handlebars.js, i18next

Pulling my hair out with regex to match the key from a handlebars template. I am using i18next-parser.
My handlebars file contains the following:

```
{{t "Some key"}}
```

I am running the following command:

```
 i18next index.handlebars -p "{{t\s+(\"(?:[^\\\\\"\\\\]|\\\\.)*\"|'(?:[^'\\\\]|\\\\.)*')?([^}]*)}}" --locales en,zh --output ../locales
```

My output locale file looks like this:

```
{"\"Some key\"": ""}
```

I am struggling to alter the regex so that the double quotes in the handlebars file are excluded from the match.

The desired output is

```
{"Some key": ""}
```

Comment: whats the expected output?

Comment: Expected output is `{"Some key": ""}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
{{t\s+(?:\"((?:[^\\\\\"\\\\]|\\\\.)*)\"|'(?:[^'\\\\]|\\\\.)*')?([^}]*)}}
```

Comment: this works well. I now want to match the above regex or the following `[^a-zA-Z0-9_](?:t)(?:\\(|\\s)\\s*(?:(?:\'((?:(?:\\\\\')?[^\']+)+[^\\\\])\')|(?:"((?:(?:\\\\")?[^"]+)+[^\\\\])"))/g`
placing both regex strings inside brackets seperated by a pipe doesn't work